# PODs restarted unexpectedly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

My development environments are running on Google Container Engine, and the following PODs created by Replication Controller

```
NAME                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       NODE
couchdb-dev-ocbud     1/1       Running   3          13h       cz5w
couchdb-stage-8f9bn   1/1       Running   1          13h       uqu4
etcd-1-rmwzy          1/1       Running   0          3d        q0cz
etcd-2-n4ckp          1/1       Running   8          3d        uqu4
etcd-3-yzz2x          1/1       Running   0          3d        yt9e
mongodb-dev-ig9xo     1/1       Running   3          16h       cz5w
mysql-dev-rykih       1/1       Running   3          17h       cz5w
mysql-stage-n240p     1/1       Running   3          16h       cz5w
redis-dev-19dxg       0/1       Running   5          3d        cz5w
redis-dev-s5v6k       1/1       Running   0          3d        yt9e
redis-dev-wccyb       0/1       Running   8          3d        uqu4
redis-stage-qnbb6     0/1       Running   8          3d        uqu4
redis-stage-xb54r     0/1       Running   0          3d        yt9e
redis-stage-xntc2     0/1       Running   5          3d        cz5w
shadowsocks-b8009     1/1       Running   0          2d        q0cz
shadowsocks-i1anu     1/1       Running   0          2d        yt9e
ts-stage-4esg8        1/1       Running   8          3d        uqu4
ts-stage-cer7a        1/1       Running   5          3d        cz5w
ts-stage-dtpdh        1/1       Running   0          3d        yt9e
ts-stage-mah7w        1/1       Running   0          3d        q0cz
uls-dev-upibo         1/1       Running   5          1d        cz5w
uls-stage-zht0j       1/1       Running   6          1d        uqu4
zookeeper-1-4dklm     1/1       Running   0          3d        q0cz
zookeeper-2-pw13k     1/1       Running   8          3d        uqu4
zookeeper-3-u9a34     1/1       Running   0          3d        yt9e
```

PODs on NODE `uqu4` were restarted for 8 times without my interaction.

Here is the termination reason from `kubectl describe pod <pod>`, error code is 137

```
Last Termination State: Terminated
  Reason:           Error
  Exit Code:        137
  Started:          Mon, 21 Mar 2016 08:33:24 +0000
  Finished:         Mon, 21 Mar 2016 21:04:57 +0000
Ready:          True
Restart Count:      8
```

When I ssh to the `uqu4` node, I receives a warning as below

> WARNING: Could not setup log file in /root/.config/gcloud/logs,
>   (OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device:
>   '/root/.config/gcloud/logs/2016.03.22')

The `df -h` looks ok

```
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                   99G   14G   82G  14% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   750M  340K  750M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6be8ff15-205a-4019-99e0-92d9c347301b   99G   14G   82G  14% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   1.5G  1.7M  1.5G   1% /run/shm
cgroup                                                  3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/46f374dc-ecbe-11e5-bf3b-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a17371c-ecbe-11e5-bf3b-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
/dev/sdb                                                976M  187M  722M  21% /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/etcd-2-data-disk
/dev/sdb                                                976M  187M  722M  21% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a13021d-ecbe-11e5-bf3b-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/etcd-data
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a13021d-ecbe-11e5-bf3b-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
/dev/sdc                                                976M  9.5M  900M   2% /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/zookeeper-2-data-disk
/dev/sdc                                                976M  9.5M  900M   2% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a5933ee-ecbe-11e5-bf3b-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/zookeeper-2-data
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4a5933ee-ecbe-11e5-bf3b-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b93210e7-ecfb-11e5-a962-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
/dev/sdd                                                 30G   48M   28G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/uls-stage-data-disk
/dev/sdd                                                 30G   48M   28G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f2764484-ee6b-11e5-a962-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/uls-stage-data-disk
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f2764484-ee6b-11e5-a962-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
/dev/sde                                                 50G   52M   47G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/couchdb-stage-data-disk
/dev/sde                                                 50G   52M   47G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/e721dfb1-ef5b-11e5-a962-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~gce-pd/couchdb-stage-data-disk
tmpfs                                                   3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/e721dfb1-ef5b-11e5-a962-42010af00080/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-binen
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6be8ff15-205a-4019-99e0-92d9c347301b   99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/8d9c854d1688439657c6b55107f6898d6b9fbdb74b9610dd0b48a1b22c6102d1
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9e09bc6c69af03192569ba25762861edd710bf45baf65c449a4caf5ad69500f3
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/f82c122422db51310ce965173ca2b043ffa7b55b84f5b28bf9c19004a3e44fa9
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/6a0ccec3cedbcdf481a2ce528f2dcc9d1626f263591bebdb96a77beea0c0443f
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ae8059fb1c2abbbffc72813a0355a4dd3d2633c720ef61b16d19a46ed2d63358
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/9d5b9ad1148e1ee4e10f826fc500f0a5c549bdc9ed66519e5f3b222d99641dfd
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/668f95f658cb13457b193f31716df5e5b8da7f227bc3ae1e0367098ec20580b0
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/bdf7d3660b81879c75a0048f921fa47b0138c3a9ec5454e85a55e62ccf9d86fe
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/8cb75d5e0df5d34ceefe41ec55a88198568a0670b6bddade4d8bb7194ba49779
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a9bb332d1aebc349d1440416a59f898f9ed12be1c744e11e8f3e502dd630df0e
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/36a2bd14af419e19fe89fe32e3f02f490f5553246e76d6c7636ae80e6bba8662
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a8c983eb3b1701263d1501b025f080ae0d967ddee2fd4bd5071e6e9297b389b9
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/e0131ab5360fce8e3a83522b9bc7176d005b893b726bf616d0ee2f7e5ab4269e
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/2e1fd00cb2ec9ca11323b3ac66f413b6873ca2e949ceb3ba5eb368de8de18af5
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/78c89fcc2b2a81c8544883209fac002a3525fed8504ebf43722b592179264dea
none                                                     99G   14G   82G  14% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4e56c31cbc3dfde7df17c1075595d80214dc81e55093ee9d9b63ef88b09502ad
```

Here is result from `free`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7679824    5625036    2054788          0     207872    1148568
-/+ buffers/cache:    4268596    3411228
Swap:            0          0          0
```

What is the reason causing the PODs restart?

Comment: I suspect the host is out of space, and Google needs to have someone intervene and evacuate all the pods to other nodes. I'm a bit surprised that this hasn't already happened.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, but the `df -h` says there is enough space

Comment: Check events `kubectl get ev`; Are you using more than 10GB of filespace in the container?

Comment: This certainly seems to be related to resources. You might be able to obtain more information on the crash by using  ¨get pod -o go-template='¨ as explained [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/#my-container-is-terminated). You could also try to check the [pod logs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend running the following commands to view the pods/nodes current state:

> - kubectl describe pod 'failing pod'
> - kubectl get pod -o go-template='{{range.status.containerStatuses}}{{"Container Name:
>     "}}{{.name}}{{"\r\nLastState: "}}{{.lastState}}{{end}}' 'failing pod'
> - kubectl describe node 'node where pod is failing'
> - kubectl get events

These commands can provide detailed information on the pods that might be failing, as well as the nodes where the pods are being created. [This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/) Kubernetes link has more information on how to determine the root cause for a pod failure.

For monitoring the resources used by pods, it's better to use the [monitoring tools](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/resource-usage-monitoring/) that Kubernetes suggest or the [Web UI (Dashboard)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/), as these tools can provide detailed information on the resources being used by every pod.